# What are the ways to model multivalued M : N relationship?

Tags: mysql

I am working on the project that requires multivalued M : N relationship.

For eg. 
There is a list of products in the `Products` table.
The user can purchase 1 or more products and are maintained in the table `Orders`. Along with this information, there is one more table that maintains analytical information.

This table should contain the hard coded data like. If the order contains product 1 and product 2 then does product 3 and product 4 also appeared in the user's order. These are basically hard coded rules

```
actual products | expected products
1,3             | 2,4
5,6,7,8         | 3,4
```

Now from these tables, I need to find information like if user's order number 1 had products like 1 and 3 then return 2 and 4.

I need suggestions as to how to describe this multivalued M to N relationship. If there are any other options other than RDBMS feel free to suggest. Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to describe a [recommendation engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recommendation_engine), or are these rules that a user must fulfil for their order to be valid?

Comment: @eggyal you got the right word to describe this problem. Yeah, it's definitely like recommendation engine. These rules must not be true for the user's order to be valid.

Answer (score 0):

You could create three additional tables:

- ProductSet(productset_id) - Stores product sets headers(one row from your sample)
- ProductSetPart(productset_id,product_id) - Stores required products to make set, in your case column actual product
- ProductSetAdditional(productset_id,product_id) - stores expected products.

Having given Order we can detect which additional products should be added.

**EDIT: sample added**

Example query that return list of Sets that are fulfilling requirements:

```
 SELECT psp.productset_id FROM 
    ProductSetPart psp LEFT JOIN 
    OrderLines ol 
ON 
    psp.product_id=ol.product_id
GROUP BY 
    psp.productset_id 
HAVING 
    -- trick - COUNT(*) will return count of all products required by aggregatet set
    -- COUNT(psp.product_id) will count only not null products 
    -- (which will be null if they aren't in order line)
    -- so if all product sets are in order line then we know,
    -- that this set requirements are full filled
    COUNT(*) = COUNT(psp.product_id)
```

Comment: I actually thought about this design earlier. The only problem I had was how do I get row from ProductSetPart. In Order table will have product_id and not product_set_id. So how query should be as to retrieve data from ProductSetPart?

Comment: sorry for late reply. But this query does not give expected result.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1a441/13